# Composer [Mac] - Unable to use composer command on cmd

Tags: php, macos, laravel, composer-php, macos-sierra

I haven't been able to install composer into my mac (running macOS Sierra) ever since I got it some time ago.

I was able to download composer into my mac and then place the ***composer.phar*** file into the ***usr/local/bin/composer*** directory, but when I try to run the `composer` command on cmd it retrieves:

```
-bash: composer: command not found
```

I'm getting desperate now. I haven't been able to develop since 3 months ago. Please help :(

Comment: Do you mean you moved it to `/usr/local/bin/composer` or to `usr/local/bin/composer`? And does the path exists in your `$export` variable? What happens when you run `which composer`?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install/upgrade Composer (and all other software on your Mac!). It's a "default" package manager in the community at the moment.

Just install Homebrew and then — Composer

```
brew install composer
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no `/usr/local/bin/composer` directory, but `/usr/local/bin`. So, make sure you install it correctly:

Delete the folder

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Download it again, then move it this way:

```
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Then make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in your path

```
$ echo $PATH
```

And you must see

```
$ /usr/local/bin
```

If it's not in your path you'll have to add this to your .bashrc (or whatever you are using as command line):

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

And you should be good to

```
composer update
```